# Github failed to Authentication

Tags: github, git-push, git-authentication

On my laptop (**operating system Ubuntu 20.04**), the git is installed and it's version is `git version 2.33.0` and I have check the configuration using below command,

`git config --list`

**command result is:**

```
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
user.name=imdadulhaque1
user.email=imdadul......@gmail.com
user.password=........
```

**N.B: I just use dot for security**

Although I have used the same user name and same password but it's failed to push and show the below error,

```
Username for 'https://github.com': imdadulhaque1
Password for 'https://imdadulhaque1@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/imdadulhaque1/LearningOpenCV_with_Projects.git/'
```

Comment: Did you read the error message and read the link and get a token?

Comment: Yes, I have opened the link and It just saying for @step Authentication and I did it . but still now it's showing this error